# Apple TextEdit - where is the file being saved?

Tags: macos, folders, textedit

I used to use Save As… to remember the directory I was saving a file in, but that seems to have disappeared with the latest OS.

I have a file open in TextEdit. How does one go about finding the directory that this file is currently being saved to? I can see the name and I can "open recent" (which just displays the name), but, once open, I can't actually figure out how to determine where this file is located.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try pressing <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd> while you left-click on the document window title text. It will show the folder hierarchy in a pop-up menu.

Comment: Hey, I didn't know this! I though this only worked for the Finder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do more than just look at the path, try this.

1. Ctrl+Click on the filename in the title bar, or secondary click. That opens the list of "Folder Proxies" (a new term for me).
2. Option+Click on the folder name, right under the filename. That opens up a Finder window with the current file selected.

If `Finder > View > Show Pathbar` has been selected, the bottom of the Finder window will show the path to the file. Rightclick on the filename at the far right end and select `Copy '<filename>' as path` to put the full path to the current file into the clipboard.